# Reactive extensions Observable.Using and WCF async call

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I'm having trouble understanding how to use Observer.Using

I've got the following code

```
    public void Test()
    {
        Observable.Using(
            () => new GFSClientServiceClient(),
            (c) => ObservableGetParameters(c))
                .Subscribe(
                    (response) => Debug.Print("response"),
                    (ex) => Debug.Print("{0} error: {1}", Name, ex.Message),
                    () => Debug.Print("{0} complete", Name)
                );
    }

    private static Func<IObservable<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>>> ObservableGetParameters(GFSClientService.GFSClientServiceClient client)
    {
        return Observable.FromAsyncPattern<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>>(client.BeginGetParameters, client.EndGetParameters);
    }
```

I can't seem to get the using clause to work. It keeps telling me that the types cannot be inferred, but I don't see why? Anybody have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT:

My first answer was incorrect.  Sorry about that.  You probably want to do something like this:

```
public void Test() 
{ 
   Observable.Using(() => new Client(), 
        (c) => ObservableGetParameters(c))
                    .Subscribe((response) => Debug.Print("response"), 
                   (ex) => Debug.Print("{0} error: {1}", "name", ex.Message), 
                   () => Debug.Print("{0} complete", "name"));
}
private static IObservable<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>> ObservableGetParameters(Client client) 
{
  return Observable.FromAsyncPattern<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>>(client.BeginGetParameters, client.EndGetParameters)(); 
  }
public class Client : IDisposable {
 public IAsyncResult BeginGetParameters(AsyncCallback cb, object o) { 
   return default(IAsyncResult);
}
public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> EndGetParameters(IAsyncResult res) {
  return default(Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>);
}
public void Dispose() {}
}
```